# Mach-O binaries using FASM

Tags: target, assembly, mach-o, fasm

is anybody using FASM to produce Mach-O binaries?
it's my assembler of choice and I thought it would be nice to learn whether that's possible to accomplish and whether somebody is already doing it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tomasz Grysztar (the author) said that Mach-O support is on the way ( http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=38075#38075 ), perhaps you should go there and ask for it to give him an extra push ;)

(edit)Sorry missed another thread: http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=9954 . There you'll see that someone succeeded by making an ELF object and then using an external tool to convert to Mach-O format before linking.